# I found that $\frac{dx}{dt} \cdot x = x$. What did I do wrong?

Tags: calculus

I found the following while fiddling around with the product rule.

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} \cdot x 
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \cdot x + x \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} x^2
= x
$$

Which is wrong iff $\frac{dx}{dt} \neq 1$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Everything is correct except the last equation.

Comment: Your last equality is wrong. $\frac 12 \frac d{dt} x^2 \ne x$ in general. You're confusing with $\frac 12 \frac d{dx} x^2 = x$.

Comment: You're a physicist, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x$, but $\frac{d}{dt}x^2=2x\frac{dx}{dt}$.

You've essentially assumed that $x=t$, in which case $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, you are absolutely right! Thank you!

Comment: If you are more ambitious about [fallacies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy)